# Why do Javascript functions work only if a php login session is active, but stop working when logged out?

Tags: javascript, php, function

In particular, I have these simple open/close tabs functions that only work if I'm logged in the website I'm making.

What's wrong?

```js
function closeFilm(){
 document.getElementById("film").classList.remove("show");
}


function showFilm() {
   document.getElementById("film").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="closeAdmin();closeSocial(); closeRicerca(); showFilm(); closeCinema();   closeLogin(); "  class="dropbtn">Film</button>
  <div id="film" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="pages/film.html" target="framecontent">Film</a>
    <a href="pages/attore.html" target="framecontent">Attori</a>
    <a href="pages/articolo.html" target="framecontent">News</a>
    <a href="pages/premi.html" target="framecontent">Premi</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is too much unknown.... What login mechanism? Cookie, Session, httpAuth, ..?

Comment: what _exactly_ isn't working? Showing the firm element -> is it loaded in html at all?

Comment: JavaScript has ZERO clue about the server session so something else you are not showing is probably the cause...

Answer (score 0):

After reading your question what I think is that the attribute having id="film" is somehow associated with the session , means when you are not logged in the id is not working and hence the JavaScript too . Please check that area . And also write all JavaScript codes under one function which are called from the same button .